# Conditional WHERE in Realm RLMSupport

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm

I have those queries in my android application:

```
RealmResults<T> results = realm.where(tClass).equalTo(key, value).findAll();
RealmResults<T> results = realm.where(tClass).findAll();
```

Now i want to code them in my ios application.
     Requirements: 
IOS  - 7.1, language - swift.
I am trying to do this using RLMSupport:

```
T.allObjectsInRealm(myRealm).filter("// dont know what i should put here")
T.allObjectsInRealm(myRealm).objectsWhere("// same problem")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, forget my previous answer! I forgot that the native version of Realm Swift isn't available on iOS 7 and you'd need to use the Swift-bridged Objective-C version.

The equivalent code would be:

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
let allObjects = MyObjectClass.allObjectsInRealm(realm)
let filteredObjects = allObjects.objectsWhere("key == value")
```

To clarify, the `filter` method is only available in Realm Swift, and its equivalent method in Objective-C is `objectsWhere()`. The filtering syntax is based on Apple's `NSPredicate` API. For more information on the syntax and what is supported in Realm's queries, there's [a cheatsheet on the Realm website](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/).